# Non-abelian Galois group of a Galois extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, galois-theory

Let $L/K$ be a Galois extension and suppose the Galois group $G(L/K)$ has order $pq$, where $pq$ are distinct primes with $p < q$. Using Sylow's theorems, one can show that $L$ is not the splitting field of a degree $p$ polynomial. Now, assume $G$ is not Abelian, I'd like to show that $L$ is actually the splitting field of a polynomial $g \in K[x]$ of degree $q$.

We already know that $L$ is the splitting field of some polynomial $g \in K[x]$. Let $\alpha \in L/K$ be a root of $g$, then $K(\alpha)$ is an intermediate field between $K$ and $L$. Hence, the degree of $K(\alpha)$ over $K$ can only be $p,q$ or $pq$. In the previous two cases, it's not hard to show that $L = K(\alpha,\beta)$ where $\beta$ is another of $g$.

However, I don't how how to conclude $\text{deg}(g) = q$ from here. I also know that a group of order $pq$ is non-abelian only if $p \mid q - 1$. But I'm not sure how to apply this fact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the Galois correspondence, there is an intermediate field $E$ with $L/E$ of degree $p$ (hence $E/K$ of degree $q$), corresponding to a subgroup of order $p$ of $G(L/K)$. By the Galois correspondence, $E$ is not Galois over $K$, since the subgroups of order $p$ are not normal in $G(L/K)$. But $E$ is a simple extension over $K$, so $E=K(\rho)$ for some $\rho\in E\setminus K$. This $\rho$ is  the root  of an irreducible polynomial in $K[x]$ of degree $q$, and its splitting field is strictly larger than $E$ (as otherwise $E$ would be a splitting field over $K$ and hence Galois over $K$), and contained in $L$ (because $L$ is Galois).